# typecasting on boolean expression in PHP

Tags: php, casting, expression

I have 3 different behaviours:

```
var_dump((int) true); // returns 1

var_dump((int) true && true); // returns true

var_dump((int) (true && true)); // returns 1
```

Why?

Comment: In 1st and 3rd expression the the boolean true is typecasted to integer,whereas in 2nd exp the first boolean value "true" is typecasted to int(since values exp within angular braces have high priority) and then the boolean exp "true && true" is evaluated (based on the priority).

Comment: See http://php.net/boolean and http://php.net/juggling and http://php.net/types.comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because casting is done first and then AND-operation, so you end up with 1 && true which is true

Answer (score 1):

```
(int)true && true;

 // same as:
 ((int) true) && true;

 // same as:
 1 && true; // = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(int) true
```

Casts TRUE as an integer (giving 1)

```
(int) true && true
```

Casts the first TRUE as an integer (giving 1), then ANDs with the second TRUE (which recasts the 1 back to a Boolean) giving TRUE

```
(int) (true && true)
```

ANDs TRUE and TRUE (giving TRUE), then casts to ain integer (giving 1)

Answer (score 1):

In first case simple type cast will work

```
var_dump((int) true); // returns 1
```

In second case first parameter will be type cast first and then  && operation will be performed that will return ...as usual true

```
var_dump((int) true && true); // returns true
```

In third  case  and operation will be implemented first  that will return true and then type cast operation will be performed that will convert true to 1

```
var_dump((int) (true && true)); // returns 1
```